# Resolve DBContext with implements another interface in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an EF Context that has it's signature

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{

}
```

When I add it to services, I use it

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(op =>
{
    op.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

But it's causing problems when I'm injecting the IDbContext, like this

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IDbContext), typeof(MyContext));
```

Because it's duplicating my DbContext, and It should be only one per request.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case using the factory method should work fine.

```
services.AddScoped<IDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService(typeof(MyContext)));
```

This way you will resolve a new instance of `MyDbContext` (on first call) or return the already instantiated instance of it during a request on conclusive calls.

Comment: Thank you! More specifically, the way it worked is  `services.AddScoped<IDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<MyContext>());`

Comment: Time saver! can I know the explanation behind it? why does it resolve to a new instance when using the syntax which OP mentioned

Comment: @mahdimahzouni: Each registration causes a new instance. So if you register with different interface, it will be new instance. The factory method doesn't create any new instances, it just resolves an existing one (or creates one, if there is none)

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that if you are registering multiple different DbContexts, you will have to correctly define the constructors using the correct specific DbContextOptions. If you don't you run the risk of having the incorrect type being resolved by the DI.

For example, I was using an `MyContext : DbContext, IDbContext`, similar to OP, but I was also using a generic `DbContext` for temporary storage for OpenIddict:

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(o =>
            {
                o.UseInMemoryDatabase(nameof(DbContext)); //tokens and stuff is stored in memory, not the actual users or passwords. 
                o.UseOpenIddict();
            });
```

Crucially, my MyContext constructor was too generic - created using a Visual Studio Quick Action template :( ugh

### Wrong:

```
public MyContext (DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { ... }
```

This results in the DI resolving the wrong DbContext at runtime:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure:Information: Entity Framework Core 2.1.4-rtm-31024 initialized 'MyContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory' with options: StoreName=DbContext
```

At some point I got an error which complained that I didn't have the right type of constructor for my context, so I changed the constructor to:

### Correct:

```
public MyContext (DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { ... }
```

and now it works right.